# let AWS RDS communicate with EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have an instance EC2 with docker-compose with my services. These services uses a MySql DB. Instead of installing mysql directly in the instance by CLI, I've created an AWS RDS instance.
The problem is that from my EC2 instance I can not connect with the DB. Moreover, if I do from my EC2 instance

```
ping xxxxxx.rds.amazonaws.com
```

there is not response.

From my EC2 instance I have 2 security groups:

- **ec2-rds-1** outbound on port 3306 to RDS
- **rds-ec2-1** inbound on port 3306
  from RDS

In my RDS instance, the EC2 already appears in the "Connected Compute Resources" section.

VPC is the same for both.

What can I do? What/where should I check for wrong configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Using `ping` is not a great test since all it does is test whether `ping` is working.

The typical security configuration would be:

- A **Security Group on the EC2 instance** (`App-SG`) that permits inbound traffic on appropriate ports for your app to receive traffic and permits **All Outbound Traffic** (which is normally the default)
- A **Security Group on the Amazon RDS instance** (`DB-SG`) that permits **All inbound traffic on port 3306 from `App-SG`**

That is, `DB-SG` specifically references `App-SG`. This way, any EC2 instance that is associated with `App-SG` will automatically be permitted to communicate with the database. Security Groups are stateful, which means that any 'return traffic' will be automatically permitted, without having to add rules.

Also, do not modify Network ACLs away from their default "Allow All" configuration.

Comment: Security groups seem ok. I also tried to delete the DB and create a new one, letting it to automatically create the groups. Inbound and Outbound rules seem ok. I can connect to the DB from my local pc, with `MySqlWorkbench`, by `SSH` on the EC2 instance. Anyway, how can I reach the DB directly from the EC2 shell? what can I use instead of `ping`?

Comment: Ping only tests whether Ping is working. You want to know whether you can connect to the database, so you should test this by connecting to the database. Download and use a MySQL command line. See: [Connecting to a DB instance running the MySQL database engine - Amazon Relational Database Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToInstance.html)

Comment: tried with `mysql -h=XXX.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com -u XXX -pXXX db_schema_name`. I get `!b#PobQ-k59C: event not found`

Comment: See: [-bash: !28: event not found · Issue #371 · interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB · GitHub](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB/issues/371)